# Getting the second argument (size) of std::array as a function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, constant-expression, stdarray

In the following code, I need to get size of the `std::array` as a function argument. I preferred `std::array` to `std::vector` since the size of the container is not supposed to change. However, the compiler complains as `error: ‘n’ is not a constant expression`. How can I obtain the size of the array through function argument?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void fnc(const int n)
{
    array<int,n> a;
}

int main()
{    
    fnc(5);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Template arguments must be expressions whose value is known at compile-time, since they become part of the type of the template specialization. Therefore, function parameters cannot be used as template arguments. This reflects that `array<int,n>` has a size fixed at *compile-time*.

Comment: If you want to have a data structure that does not allowed size changes, you can write a thin wrapper of `std::vector`.

Comment: @Shibli Your example doesn't show you calling `fnc` with the right arguments. How do you plan to use it?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. The size of an array must be constant expression - which means it must be known during compilation. If it is a function argument it is not possible, since the function can be called with any argument. Use std::vector - most likely you won't see any performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters aren't constant expressions. Use a template argument instead:

```c++
template<int n>
void fnc()
{
    std::array<int, n> a;
}

int main()
{
    fnc<5>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a templated function like this

```
template <size_t N>
void func()
{
array<int, N> a;
}

int main()
{
func<5>();
return 0;
}
```

This works as long as the size of the `std::array` you want to create is known at compile time.